# Making parts of image transparent - am I doing it right?

Tags: icon, transparency, paint.net

First, I want to make it very clear that I am a newbie in the graphic design field and I have no idea of how things are done. I am more a programmer than a designer.

I have been making a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prokeys/ekfnbpgmmeahnnlpjibofkobpdkifapn), but in it they say that the app icon provided should be:

> The actual icon size should be 96x96 (for square icons); an additional 16 pixels per side should be transparent padding, adding up to 128x128 total image size. For details, see Icon size.

What do I do now? What I actually did is:

1. Create a square icon (initial logo) of size 128x128.

[image: image logo attempt 1]

2. Delete 16 pixels on each side, so that they become transparent.

[image: image logo attempt 2]

Did I do it correctly? I mean, the second step. I don't have any idea of whether what I did was right or wrong. I really fear that I have done something wrong that may affect my app rating.

Maybe, did I have to use the Magic Wand tool?

I am using Paint.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your actual icon should be 96 by 96 pixels with a transparent padding that adds up to 128 by 128 pixels.

First of all, what you did in the second step was reduce the size of the green background of your logo. I assume you want to keep the full logo without actually reducing its background.

First, open your logo as it is, 128x128 pixels. I downloaded your logo just to show how this will work.

[image]

Then, go to the image tab and choose resize, then adjust it to 96x96 pixels, this will resize you logo to the 96x96 pixel size.

[image]

[image]

At this point, your logo size will be reduced to 96x96 pixels, without reducing the green background color as you can see

[image]

now the next step, go to the image tab again but this time choose canvas size. Now you resize the canvas size to 128x128 pixels. make sure you adjust the image icon to the center as shown, this will result in increasing canvas size to 128x128pixels, creating that white padding that is shown in the image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now we have that white padding, but that's not what we want right? we want the padding to be transparent. Now choose the magic wand tool from the tool panel on the left. its the one that looks like a black stick.

[image]

We are almost done, now select the white padding area with the magic wand tool. this will only select the white area as shown.

[image]

After you selected the white padding area, simply press delete on your keyboard and that should the white padding, leaving you with this transparent padding as shown.

[image]

You are done! now just save the image as a png file in order to keep the transparent padding. jpegs don't have an alpha value thus can't keep transparencies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! That's a comprehensive, and well detailed in-depth answer! Thanks a lot :) Also, if you have time, would you please view the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prokeys/ekfnbpgmmeahnnlpjibofkobpdkifapn) and look over its graphical design, I mean, the main promotional video. Specifically, which background (or gradient), font style, font color should I use for that video? Just this help and I promise to trouble no more! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, here are some quick tips for the video
-For the background, a white color should be fine. 
-I think you should just use a regular sans-serif font with the color black. and make the text to alight to the left, that way it will be easier to read.
-for the title of your app, PRO KEY, the 'PRO' part would be nice if it was the same size as the box encapsulating the 'KEY' word.
-and lastly, I think you should change the background music to a more soothing song to not distract your viewer. maybe you can record yourself explaining the app instead.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot! I will look into this when I finish the current version of the app, thank you!